# StopPropogation - not working to disable parent anchor tags

Tags: jquery, click, stoppropagation

I am currently trying to change the color of a child element on click. The parent element links to another page. I was hoping stopPropogation would work, but it isn't. The following is my jQuery code:

```
$('.child').click(function(){

    if($(this).hasClass('pinned')){

        $(this).removeClass('pinned')

    }

    else{

        $(this).addClass('pinned')

    }

}); 

    // disable parent link when pinning

    $('.child').click(function(event){

        event.stopPropagation();

    });
```

If it matters, the anchor tag surrounds the grandparent.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.child').click(function(e) {
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).removeClass('pinned');
    }
    else {
        $(this).addClass('pinned');
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

You can use `e.stopPropagation` in same function.

Comment: Thank you! I can expect the answer in 2 more minutes. :)